# How to display html code received from a fetch request in vue?

Tags: html, api, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implement html code that I am receiving from an api into my code in vuejs. So from the api I am getting:

```
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<ul>
<li>
1
</li>
<li>
2
</li>
</ul>
```

I am saving this chunk of code into a variable, but when I implement them in the template like this  {{variable.information}} nothing shows up. How do I display this chunk of code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

pass it to v-html directive in the template.
Mandatory warning: Be aware of XSS vulnerabilities and only use for trusted content.

```
<div v-html="variable.information" />
```